# How can I bound a Google map by setting contraints on borders and not on the center

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to prevent the top of the map from going above a latitude of 85. There seem to be no direct API to do this, and what I've found is about setting bounds on the center of the map, using the `setCenter` function. However, because of the deformation created by the map projection, I can't find by how much I should move the center to have the top to stay within the bounds.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
  var top = map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat();
  if (top > 85) {
    var c = map.getCenter();
    map.setCenter({lat: c.lat() - (top - 85), lng: c.lng()});
  }
});
```

Here the offset `(top - 85)` is not large enough and this results in an annoying never ending repositioning, because changing position doesn't correct the position by enough and the function gets called again. What I want is a clear cut off where the map doesn't go at all above the 85 latitude.

Comment: [Mike Williams' discussion of this in his v2 tutorial page: "Limiting the range"](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/range.htm) (Note that [the Google Maps Javascript API v2](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-maps-api-2/info) is deprecated and turned off)

Comment: looking at the code source of http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_range.htm (from your link) shows that the range used is on the center of the map, not the edges. I could not find the relation between the center and the edges because 1) it's depends of the zoom level and 2) involves reverse engineering google map's projection, at least from my understanding